# How to use SUMIF to add values by unique Reference ID?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to write a formula that adds cell values by matching the reference ID in a separate column. For example, cells `G2` and `G3` have the same ID, so the amounts in cell `H2` and `H3` would be added together, and that total, $21.12, would appear in both `I2` and `I3`.

[image]

I've been trying to use SUMIF for this, but have only been successful when specifying the exact reference ID in the formula.  I need the formula to automatically match based on any Reference ID. Is there any way to use a SUMIF (or another function altogether) to match strings to calculate values?

Answer (score 0):

- Use [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) to SUM Column B and group by Column A
- [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)to find totals by Reference ID
- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) to use a single formula for all transaction IDs
- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) limits [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) only to those rows containing at least one character.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(FILTER(A2:A,LEN(A2:A)>0), 
    QUERY(A:B, "select A, SUM(B) group by A"),2))
```

[image]